# How to add @types dependences in DefinitelyTyped packages?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

My package in DefinitelyTyped should dependence on `@types/webvr-api`.
However, there is no `package.json` in DefinitelyTyped.
Here is the link: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/playcanvas

How can I add `@types/webvr-api` for my package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/// <reference types="..." />` [directive](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-types-), [you can find plenty examples with this search](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=reference+typed&type=), [like this one in riotjs-render.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/riotjs/riotjs-render.d.ts#L6)

```
/// <reference types="jquery" />
```

Comment: Do I need to put `jquery.d.ts` in the folder ?

Comment: I don't think so, but anyone who will use your typings will have to have jquery typings installed, so it might make sense to add them as dev dependency to your main package